# limit of $4x\sin(\frac1x)$

Tags: limits, trigonometry, limits-without-lhopital

I'm having a bit of a problem taking the limit of functions involving $\sin(\dfrac1x)$.

Mainly, I don't know whether or not L'Hopital's rule is required. Here's the particular problem:

$$\lim\limits_{x\to \infty} 4x\sin (\frac1x)= ?$$

Comment: Set $1/x=h,h\to0^+$

Comment: write your limit as $$4\lim_{?}\frac{\sin(\frac{1}{x})}{\frac{1}{x}} $$

Comment: when I hear "inverse trig functions" I think of $\sin^{-1}(x)$ et al.

Comment: I edited the question accordingly

Answer (score 2):

$$
\lim_{x\to \infty}\left[4x\sin\left(\frac1x\right)\right]=
4\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{ \sin\left(\frac1x\right)}{\frac1x}
$$

As $x\to\infty$, $\frac1x \to0$. Substitute $\frac1x$ with a new variable ($\theta=\frac1x$):

$$
4\lim_{\theta\to 0}\frac{ \sin\theta}{\theta}=4\cdot 1=4.
$$

$\displaystyle\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=1$ is a well-known limit and the fact that it's equal to 1 is [proven](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75130/how-to-prove-that-lim-limits-x-to0-frac-sin-xx-1) in elementary calculus.

Or you can use L'Hospital's rule (the indeterminate form is $\frac00$):

$$4\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\sin\left(\frac1x\right)}{\frac1x}\stackrel{\text{L'H}}{=}
4\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\left[\sin\left(\frac1x\right)\right]'}{\left(\frac1x\right)'}=4\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\cos{\left(\frac1x\right)}\left(-\frac{1}{x^2}\right)}{-\frac{1}{x^2}}=\\
4\lim_{x\to\infty}\cos{\left(\frac1x\right)}=4\cdot\cos{0}=4\cdot 1=4.
$$

Comment: Thanks, another thing: could you use l'hopital's for this or is that restricted to rational functions?

Comment: Sure. See the post. I made some changes.

Comment: Thanks so much! This is way more in line with how we're learning it in school

Comment: To the proposer: Review the necessary and sufficient conditions on the functions in the complete statement of l'Hopital's Rule. Observe that those conditions are very broad and do not exclude any particular type (i.e. trig, exponential,etc.) of functions.

Answer (score 0):

Let $h=1/x$. As $x\to \infty$, $h\to 0$.

$$\lim_{x\to \infty}4x\sin\left(\dfrac{1}{x}\right)=4\cdot\lim_{x\to \infty}\dfrac{\sin\left(1/x\right)}{1/x}\mapsto4\cdot\underbrace{\lim_{h\to 0}\dfrac{\sin h}{h}}_{\to 1}\to 4$$